# Playing an asset with 'audioplayers' package in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Can anybody tell me how to use this latest library to play a single audio file present in the asset folder of the root of flutter? The code sample of this library on pub.dev is quite difficult to understand

Answer (score 5):

Below code block worked for me.

```
     TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final player = AudioPlayer();
              player.play(AssetSource('note1.wav'));
            },
            child: Text('click me'),
          ),
```

When you press the **Click me** button note1.wav audio file will play.

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as the following snippet. Where `click.mp3` is inside the `assets` folder.

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
player.play(AssetSource('click.mp3')),
```

A complete example:

```dart
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  AudioPlayer? _player;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _player?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _play() {
    _player?.dispose();
    final player = _player = AudioPlayer();
    player.play(AssetSource('click.mp3'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            Text(
              'Click on the play button to play a sound',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _play,
        tooltip: 'Play',
        child: const Icon(Icons.volume_up),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to follow this but it is saying not found: /data/user/0/com.MyOwner.MyApp/cache/sounds/click.mp3: open failed. Why it is looking in the cache? And How I can set it to look in the assets?

Answer (score 0):

First create an instance of `AudioPlayer` class.

`final player = AudioPlayer();`

then add asset file in `player.setSource` method.

`await player.setSource(AssetSource('sounds/coin.wav'));`

For more [Getting Started](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md) documentation

Comment: I tried to follow this but it is saying not found: /data/user/0/com.MyOwner.MyApp/cache/sounds/coin.wav: open failed. Why it is looking in the cache? And How I can set it to look in the assets?